# Distinct a list of strings ignoring white-space, diacritics and cases

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

Given the following list of strings:

```
string[] Itens = new string[] { "hi", " hi   ", "HI", "hí", " Hî", "hi hi", " hí hí ", "olá", "OLÁ", " olá   ", "", "ola", "hola", " holà    ", "aaaa", "áâàa", " aâàa     ", "áaàa", "áâaa ", "aaaa ", "áâaa", "áâaa", };
```

The result of the Distinct operation should be:

```
hi, hi hi, olá, , hola, aaaa
```

C#'s Distinct operation available to IEnumerable accepts an IEqualityComparer as parameter so we can personalize the comparation.

The following implementations gets the job done

```
class LengthHash : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return x == y;

        var xt = x.Trim();
        var yt = y.Trim();

        return xt.Length == yt.Length && Culture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(xt, yt, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj) => obj?.Trim().Length ?? 1;
}
```

If GetHashCode is different the Equals don't even execute, so it is important to have a good implementation.

I have tried changing the GetHashCode to other 2 different approaches.

**IgnoreHash**

```
public int GetHashCode(string obj) => 1;
```

**NormalizedHash**

```
public int GetHashCode(string obj) => obj?.Trim().Normalize().ToUpperInvariant().GetHashCode() ?? 1;
// obs: This approach doesn't produce the same output.
```

Beyond using a personalized IEqualityComparer I have also have tried trimming the list before doing a StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, but it produces the same output as the Normalize and Upper version.

Doing a benchmark on the pure Distinct,  StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase and the 3 personalized approaches produce the following results:

```
                              Method |       Mean |    StdErr |    StdDev |     Median |
------------------------------------ |----------- |---------- |---------- |----------- |
                          RunDefault |  2.2224 us | 0.0242 us | 0.2391 us |  2.1414 us |
                     RunHashAsLength |  6.0765 us | 0.0515 us | 0.1857 us |  6.1235 us |
                       RunIgnoreHash |  6.4078 us | 0.0640 us | 0.6140 us |  6.1982 us |
                   RunNormalizedHash | 14.5941 us | 0.0742 us | 0.3556 us | 14.4983 us |
 RunTrimAndCompareWithStringComparer | 14.4935 us | 0.0213 us | 0.0768 us | 14.5352 us |
```

The outputs are:

```
21 Default: hi,  hi   , HI, hí,  Hî, hi hi,  hí hí , olá, OLÁ,  olá   , , ola, hola,  holà    , aaaa, áâàa,  aâàa     , áaàa, áâaa , aaaa , áâaa
6 HashAsLength: hi, hi hi, olá, , hola, aaaa
6 IgnoreHash: hi, hi hi, olá, , hola, aaaa
15 NormalizedHash: hi, hí,  Hî, hi hi,  hí hí , olá, , ola, hola,  holà    , aaaa, áâàa,  aâàa     , áaàa, áâaa
15 RunTrimAndCompareWithStringComparer: hi, hí, Hî, hi hi, hí hí, olá, , ola, hola, holà, aaaa, áâàa, aâàa, áaàa, áâaa
```

You can find the full test in https://gist.github.com/Flash3001/d50a6b43bba7bc61e3d85734e40dbed9

The question is: **Is there a better approach to getting to desired final list? Be it a different GetHashCode, Equals or other pre-defined IEqualityComparer.**

Comment: Your code does not really remove diacritics , but rather appears to rely on a culture sensitive comparison.  I do not know what `Culture` is defined as, but I replaced it with `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` and it fails when test this list `{"\u212B", "\u00C5", "\u0041\u030A"}`; three different Unicode representations for the Angstrom symbol.  It should return one distinct item, but it returns two items.  That stated, I can not see any way around using a custom IEqualityComparer.

Comment: @TnTinMn The goal is not to remove diacritics, spaces, and cases but to get a distinct list where all of those are ignored, the actual 'version' of the value is irrelevant. Given the  {"\u212B", "\u00C5", "\u0041\u030A"} issue, it seems to be a better option to normalize the values before doing the Distinct.

Comment: Somewhat improved version: https://gist.github.com/Flash3001/9273494a8d94d7d9ae99cbcd8dac780a

Applied the Trim and Normalize before trying to distinct, also removed NormalizedHash as it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the designated methods provided by the `CompareInfo` class, the `Compare` and `GetHashCode`. This way you can be sure that the implementation will be consistent. Correctness comes first. Performance is secondary.

```
class StringEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    private CultureInfo _cultureInfo;
    private CompareOptions _options;
    private bool _trim;

    public StringEqualityComparer(CultureInfo cultureInfo,
        CompareOptions options, bool trim)
    {
        _cultureInfo = cultureInfo;
        _options = options;
        _trim = trim;
    }

    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        if (_trim) { x = x?.Trim(); y = y?.Trim(); }
        return _cultureInfo.CompareInfo.Compare(x, y, _options) == 0;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        if (_trim) obj = obj?.Trim();
        return _cultureInfo.CompareInfo.GetHashCode(obj, _options);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var comparer = new StringEqualityComparer(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase, true);
var items = new string[] { "hi", " hi   ", "HI", "hí", " Hî", "hi hi", " hí hí ",
    "olá", "OLÁ", " olá   ", "", "ola", "hola", " holà    ", "aaaa", "áâàa",
    " aâàa     ", "áaàa", "áâaa ", "aaaa ", "áâaa", "áâaa", };
Console.WriteLine($"Distinct: {String.Join(", ", items.Distinct(comparer))}");
```

Output:

> Distinct: hi, hi hi, olá, , hola, aaaa